# Difference between @target and @annotation

Tags: java, spring-aop

In spring aop doc, it says:

> @target - limits matching to join points (the execution of methods
>   when using Spring AOP) where the class of the executing object has an
>   annotation of the given type
>
> @annotation - limits matching to join points where the subject of the
>   join point (method being executed in Spring AOP) has the given
>   annotation

I think @target will match if the object has the given annotation like

```
@MyAnnotation
public class Foo {}
```

while @annotation will match the annotation on method, like :

```
public class Foo {

    @MyAnnotation
    public void doSomething() {}
}
```

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, your understanding here is correct. Your own answer below is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened this question based on this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6431), [wilkinsona](https://github.com/wilkinsona) gave the answer:

> The key difference is that @target matches the runtime type whereas @annotation matches the statically declared type.

Comment: I disagree. The key difference is what you describe in your own question's sample code. So you knew the answer all along. Next time maybe just try and see what happens.